# adding rel="external" to every link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I need to add rel="external" to every link () on my site is this possible?

so far i have tried `$(".content a").attr("rel","external”);`

I would add them manually but it is a 1000 page site and don't really want to code it on every link

thanks in advance

Comment: Did the code above work? If not what happened? How did you test it?

Comment: hi i put it in my JS file at the bottom of the page, am i right in saying that this should add rel="external" to every a tag inside .content ???? i am using jQuery mobile ( which is why this problem has come about, sorry should have put that above)

Comment: But *how* do you know this isn't working? How did you check? How did you test this?

Comment: apologies, it was through code inspector. not one link has rel="external"

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on **all** your links then you have to iterate through all of them and change that attribute

```
$(function () {
  $('a').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('rel', 'external');
  });
});
```

If your intent is to change every link **within** the element with class `content` then what you have should properly change it just wrap it in the function

```
$(function () {
  $('.content a').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('rel', 'external');
  });
});
```

Inspect the links in this jsfiddle to see that the attr has been added to those existing links
http://jsfiddle.net/4d06xb0x/

Comment: would this change whats there or add it?

Comment: Check out my edit. This will add that `rel=external` attr to every link inside the div(s) with class `content`.